# Permit acces to one directory only htaccess Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My Apache webserver 2.4 has 3 sub directories:

Root / Dir1
Root / Dir2
Root / Dir3

How can I permit access to Dir2 only in my root .htaccess file ?
I have been trying for hours now...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deny access to `Dir1` and `Dir3`, e.g.:

1. Create a `.htaccess` file in `Dir1` and `Dir3` with the following content:

   ```
   Require all denied
   ```
2. Add two `Redirect`s to your main `.htaccess`:

   ```
   Redirect 403 /Dir1
   Redirect 403 /Dir3
   ```

Related:

- [Require Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) (Apache Module mod_authz_core)
- [Redirect Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (Apache Module mod_alias)

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to tell that I have more then 3 directories, but 40. Root and 40 sub directories .That why I want it in one .htaccess file in the root. Sorry for my misinformation.

Comment: Then maybe the second method?

Comment: I could use that, but I was hoping there is something like "Require all denied" "except" Dir2

Comment: Sure, you could put `Require all denied` in your main `.htaccess` and `Require all granted` in `Dir2/.htaccess`, but that would also deny everything else in your root.